# Jquery Tabbed Content (Display Issue)

Tags: jquery, css

Im using this 
http://jsfiddle.net/vRqcb/11/

I've implemented that into a jquery popout box which uses this CSS:

```
#element_to_pop_up { 
    background-color:#fff;
    border-radius:15px;
    color:#000;
    display:none; 
    padding:20px;
    min-width:700px;
    min-height: 500px;
}
```

See here : http://www.pazzle.co.uk/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=6_11&products_id=8#.UIpb2cWlUYM

Underneath the ADD TO CART button it says "View Size Chart". Click that and you can see that it is a little distorted, the CSS is exactly the same as the JSfiddle?

maybe because it's in the popout script?

EDIT:

```
<!-- Element to pop up -->
<div id="element_to_pop_up">
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {    

$('#tabs li a:not(:first)').addClass('inactive');
$('.container').hide();
$('.container:first').show();

$('#tabs li a').click(function(){
    var t = $(this).attr('id');
  if($(this).hasClass('inactive')){ //this is the start of our condition 
    $('#tabs li a').addClass('inactive');           
    $(this).removeClass('inactive');

    $('.container').hide();
    $('#'+ t + 'C').fadeIn('slow');
 }
});

});
</script>
    <a class="bClose">x<a/>

<ul id="tabs">

      <li><a id="tab1">test1</a></li>
      <li><a id="tab2">test2</a></li>
      <li><a id="tab3">test3</a></li>
      <li><a id="tab4">test4</a></li>
</ul>
          <div class="container" id="tab1C">1Some content</div>
          <div class="container" id="tab2C">2Some content</div>
          <div class="container" id="tab3C">3Some content</div>
          <div class="container" id="tab4C">4Some content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am quite confident that the Javascript you're using in jsfiddle is not the same as in you have used on your website.

I see an extra anchor tag in the first li.

```
<ul id="tabs"><a>

      </a><li><a></a><a id="tab1" class="inactive">test1</a></li>
      <li><a id="tab2" class="inactive">test2</a></li>
      <li><a id="tab3" class="inactive">test3</a></li>
      <li><a id="tab4" class="inactive">test4</a></li>

</ul>
```

Also you see that the 'inactive' class is applied to all the li, while it shouldn't be applied to the first element according to your code. So this anchor tag is surely there when your javascript runs.

Comment: Im really confused, I see the extra tags but they are not there in my code. I will post what I have in the OP as an edit

Answer (score 0):

There is a double `<a>` tag in the first `<li>` of `ul#tabs`, the first `<a>` pushes the second `<a>` down.

Comment: The second <a> is not in my code, where is this being applied?